# How to Move RaisedButton to Bottom Center of The Screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I try to move `RaisedButton()` from center of the screen to bottom center. I have tried with `Align()` but not work. How to do it?

[Screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXjsE.png)

And here my code:

```
body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('images/Logoku (Dark).jpg'),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Go to First Page'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the Column with Stack and put the Centre widget in the correct order.

```
body: Stack(

        children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
            
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('images/Logoku (Dark).jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go to First Page'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Center will make it's bets efforts to center the child. However since you are using a column, it will make the column the minium height possible. Since it seems like you want to have the image at the middle, i would not use center, i would use Spacers.

```
body:  Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Spacer(),
            Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('images/Logoku (Dark).jpg'),
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Go to First Page'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not work because you set column to mainAxisALignment.center which **force** its children to be center and you know that column main axis is top to bottom.Remove **MainAxisALignment.center**.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could do the work,

```
 body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: Image(
                  image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/200'),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text('Go to First Page'),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

**Output:**

[image]